# AvPlayerLayer not Sizing correctly?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, avplayer

I have a carousel object with a UIImageView where I am trying to subLayer the AvPlayerLayer.

It works perfectly fine though it doesn't fill the full bounds of the _videoView it appears to be smaller in height, though i have tested changing the height to extreme values and it still sits at that size as long as its overlapping the UIImageView.

The code I am using to achieve this is below:

```
    UIView *embeddedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_videoView.bounds];
embeddedView.center = CGPointMake(100, 140);
AVPlayerItem *avPlayeritem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex]]];
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:avPlayeritem];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
[avPlayerLayer setFrame:embeddedView.frame];
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
[avPlayerLayer setNeedsLayout];
[embeddedView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
[carousel.currentItemView addSubview:embeddedView];
//Assign to notication to check for end of playback
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:avPlayeritem];
[avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[avPlayer play];
```

Here is an image of whats happening, as you can tell its off on the top as well as the bottom:
[image: viewOffBounds]

Whats causing this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it's logic that the video doesn't fill the full bounds of the `videoView`, because you set `avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`.
You should set it to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`, and it'll will be ok.

The difference is:

- `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` - show the video proportional to the original size, and don't allow any deformation.
- `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` - resize the video, to fill the full bounds of its subview, and don't care about proportionality.

And one last thing, do `[avPlayerLayer setFrame:embeddedView.bounds]` it's better than `[avPlayerLayer setFrame:embeddedView.frame]`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avlayervideogravityresizeaspectfill
with AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill the proportions are kept and as I understand it, are clipped

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer won't solve the problem of duplicate, overlapping layers. Instead, try not to `addSublayer` and create an AVPlayer-backed view:

Swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

/// A simple `UIView` subclass that is backed by an `AVPlayerLayer` layer.
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Objective-C

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface PlayerView : UIView
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation PlayerView
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}
- (AVPlayer*)player {
    return [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] player];
}
- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player {
    [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}
@end
```

This way, the layer will resize properly with the view.

References:

1. [Swift sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Listings/Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerView_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016103-Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerView_swift-DontLinkElementID_14)
2. [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)